# What are the perceived advantages that bitcoin has over other currencies or other ways of sending money?

Tags: key-selling-points

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the perceived advantages of bitcoin as a means of exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-are-the-perceived-advantages-of-bitcoin-as-a-means-of-exchange)

Suppose that the value of Bitcoin in USD magically remained constant from this day forward. What **unique** advantages does Bitcoin has other its alternatives (e.g. USD, Paypal)