# Is it possible to reverse mistaken transactions?

Tags: transactions

I'm referring to the challenge Bill Gates raised as a shortcoming of Bitcoin. Could it ever be possible to reverse a bitcoin transaction mistakenly sent to the wrong address?

Comment: It's actually one of the fundamental traits of Bitcoin that Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed. I expect escrow services to spring up to fill the demand for reversable transactions. Anyway, it seems your question is a duplicate of [Can a Bitcoin transaction be reversed?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/197/5406), or [Is there any study or research of how to make BTC transfers refundable?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12108/5406) Unless your question changes due to the context of the challenge you mentioned, in which case you should perhaps explain what distincts it to the above.

Comment: (cont.) To do so, it would be best to edit your question in corresponding manner, and to flag for reopening.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not a bad question, I just don't think that it would have a different answer than the ones I linked. This one might also be interesting: [What happens if I mistype the address when making a payment?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/194/5406)