# I sent bitcoin to the same address a second time, how can I recover it?

Tags: transactions

I accidentally sent $28 in bitcoin to this address 32o7Pt42rsUFupN9sNLYJdQc6MNji5rANg a second time, and it never posted to the account to which I intended to send it. I have found the transaction in the Block Explorer, it has been confirmed 611 times. Now I am wondering how I may be able to get that bitcoin back in my possession. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a bitcoin transaction be reversed?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/197/can-a-bitcoin-transaction-be-reversed)

Comment: Get in touch with your business partner, they are now in control of those funds.

Answer (score 1):

> I accidentally sent $28 in bitcoin to this address 32o7Pt42rsUFupN9sNLYJdQc6MNji5rANg **a second time**, and it never posted to the account

It sounds like you are depositing to a service. You should get in contact with the admins at that website or service to see if they can credit your account.